# Run function every 24hrs swift 3

Tags: swift3, nsdate, swift4

I got a list of quotes I am trying to update every 24hrs, based on the calender.

This is what I tried so far, but I am getting error **Cannot convert value of type 'Date?' to expected argument type 'TimeInterval' (aka 'Double')**

```
let numberOfQuotes = 3
let quotes = ["quote 1", "quote 2", "quote 3"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(30),
      target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateQuote), userInfo: nil,  repeats: true)
}

@objc func updateQuote() {
    let lastUpdate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "lastUpdate") as? Date
    if lastUpdate != nil {
        let date1:Date = Date() // Same you did before with timeNow variable
        let date2: Date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: lastUpdate ) // **Getting error on this line**

        let calender:Calendar = Calendar.current
        let components: DateComponents = calender.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date1, to: date2)

        if components.day! >= 1 {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "lastUpdate")
         textView.text = "Hello there"
        }

    } else { //firstTime running
        UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "lastUpdate")
        textView.text = quotes[randomInt(min: 0,max: numberOfQuotes)]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lastUpdate` is already a `Date`, the initializer `Date(timeIntervalSince1970:` is wrong and not needed anyway.

It's highly recommended to use optional bindings, and don't annotate types the compiler can infer.

```
if let lastUpdate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "lastUpdate") as? Date {
    let date1 = Date()

    let calender = Calendar.current
    let components = calender.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date1, to: lastUpdate)
...
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried your suggestion and change **if components.minute! >= 20** instead of waiting for a day and nothing happens. I know the time is greater than 20 minutes, it's over 1 hour.

Comment: Consider that the difference **from** *now* **to** an earlier date is **negative**. You might use `... from: lastUpdate, to: date1`

Comment: thanks for your help. The code ran once, it's not repeating every 30-sec which is on repeating timer.

Comment: I thought the timer would be repeating every 30sec after the view loads. I am new to swift, so maybe i am missing something.

Comment: @IamWayne you need to declare your timer as a property of your view controller. Btw Why do you need to update your timer every 30s if you just need to update every 24h ? Btw is it 24h from the last update or when the day changes you need to update your App?

Comment: @Leo, thanks for your response. I was testing with the timer, I needed to be updated 24hrs from the last update.

Answer (score 1):

```
let date2: Date  = lastUpdate!
```

UPDATE:

```
let components: DateComponents = calender.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date2, to: date1)
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried your suggestion and change **if components.minute! >= 20** instead of waiting for a day and nothing happens. I know the time is greater than 20 minutes, it's over 1 hour.

Comment: thanks for your help. The code ran once, it's not repeating every 30-sec which is on repeating timer.

Comment: The code for the timer is correct. You invalidate it somewhere else

Comment: the timer is still valid, it's getting called every 20 minutes. which is what I wanted, just have to change the date component to 1 day. Thanks for your help, I dont know who to give the bounty. Both of you guys helped me out..

Comment: accept vadian's answer. I think it is better than mine. For me it will be fine if you just upvote my answer